# Custom mojos with maven modules

Tags: maven, module, mojo, maven-module

I have a simple Maven multi-module project

```
Parent project
     ---Child project 1
     ---Child project 2 (depends on child project 1)
```

In the first project, I have a custom MOJO defined that I can call like this
`com.mycompany:child1artifactid:mojoname`

Is it possible to call this same mojo from the child project since it is a dependency and bundled up as a jar for the second project?
`com.mycompany:child2artifactid:mojoname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

When you invoke Maven with a plugin goal, it looks for a definition of this plugin in the project POM Maven is executed on. Since you are executing Maven on `child2artifactid`, and since this module does not declare `mojoname`, it won't work.

Now, think about it, why would you want to do this? Invoking a plugin defined in another project is not really useful: either this project declares the plugin or you invoke Maven on the other project.

Note however that when dealing with multi-module project, you often do not want to run Maven on child modules but simply on the parent project.